# How do you make something move to the previous mousepressed location?

Tags: processing

It's really basic but for example, I draw a rectangle and press somewhere (x,y), nothing happens but when I press again somewhere else(x2, y2), that rectangle will move to the first place I press(x, y). So wherever I press, the rectangle will move to the last place I press.

I have it so that the rect appears wherever I press but not the previous location.

```java
void setup(){
  background(234);
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw(){
}

void mousePressed(){
  background(234);
  rect(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create your own variables, store the previously clicked position in that, and then use that to draw your rectangle.

```java
float targetX;
float targetY;

void setup(){
  background(234);
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw(){
}

void mousePressed(){
  background(234);
  rect(targetX, targetY, 20, 20);
  targetX = mouseX;
  targetY = mouseY;
}
```

Notice that you'll have to decide what you want them to be the first time you click, since you don't have a previously clicked position yet. The default is `0, 0` in the upper-left corner.